# MYSQL date range select statement

Tags: mysql

I'm looking for help with a single SELECT statement. My answer/example using two statements:

1st: 40 days from now out to 365 days from now 
2nd: NOW out to 40 days

equals all 365 days with a start date 40 days from now

select statement 1:

SELECT id FROM sales
 WHERE (saledate BETWEEN DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 40 DAY) AND DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 365 DAY))
 ORDER BY saledate;

select statement 2:

SELECT id FROM sales
 WHERE (saledate BETWEEN NOW() AND DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 40 DAY))
 ORDER BY saledate;

Comment: Give us an sqlfiddle. Your question is not a simple one, so we need some sample data to experiment with the query.

Comment: Yes, this is possible in one SELECT. And the way you are thinking seems good to me. Now: What is your question? Doesn't it work? What have you tried already?